# Kendo UI Grid - How do I pass a selected item ID to an MVC view containing another grid?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid

I've followed [this](http://www.kendoui.com/code-library/web/grid/select-grid-rows-using-checkboxes-and-preserve-it-between-the-pages.aspx) example from the Kendo UI Web Grid code library. I'm looking to modify the existing JavaScript and replace the alert with a method to send the selected item ID to another view with a slightly different grid. Here is the code from the example. Any suggestions?

```
    <div id="grid"></div>
<button id="showSelection">Show selected IDs</button>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        //DataSource definition
        var crudServiceBaseUrl = "http://demos.kendoui.com/service",
            dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                transport: {
                    read: {
                        url: crudServiceBaseUrl + "/Products",
                        dataType: "jsonp"
                    },
                    update: {
                        url: crudServiceBaseUrl + "/Products/Update",
                        dataType: "jsonp"
                    },
                    destroy: {
                        url: crudServiceBaseUrl + "/Products/Destroy",
                        dataType: "jsonp"
                    },
                    create: {
                        url: crudServiceBaseUrl + "/Products/Create",
                        dataType: "jsonp"
                    },
                    parameterMap: function (options, operation) {
                        if (operation !== "read" && options.models) {
                            return {
                                models: kendo.stringify(options.models)
                            };
                        }
                    }
                },
                batch: true,
                pageSize: 20,
                schema: {
                    model: {
                        id: "ProductID",
                        fields: {
                            ProductID: {
                                editable: false,
                                nullable: true
                            },
                            ProductName: {
                                validation: {
                                    required: true
                                }
                            },
                            UnitPrice: {
                                type: "number",
                                validation: {
                                    required: true,
                                    min: 1
                                }
                            },
                            Discontinued: {
                                type: "boolean"
                            },
                            UnitsInStock: {
                                type: "number",
                                validation: {
                                    min: 0,
                                    required: true
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

        //Grid definition
        var grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
            dataSource: dataSource,
            pageable: true,
            height: 430,
            //define dataBound event handler
            dataBound: onDataBound,
            toolbar: ["create"],
            columns: [
                //define template column with checkbox and attach click event handler
                { template: "<input type='checkbox' class='checkbox' />" },
                "ProductName", {
                    field: "UnitPrice",
                    title: "Unit Price",
                    format: "{0:c}",
                    width: "100px"
                }, {
                    field: "UnitsInStock",
                    title: "Units In Stock",
                    width: "100px"
                }, {
                    field: "Discontinued",
                    width: "100px"
                }, {
                    command: ["edit", "destroy"],
                    title: "&nbsp;",
                    width: "172px"
                }
            ],
            editable: "inline"
        }).data("kendoGrid");

        //bind click event to the checkbox
        grid.table.on("click", ".checkbox" , selectRow);

        $("#showSelection").bind("click", function () {
            var checked = [];
            for(var i in checkedIds){
                if(checkedIds[i]){
                    checked.push(i);
                }
            }

            alert(checked);
        });
    });

    var checkedIds = {};

    //on click of the checkbox:
    function selectRow() {
        var checked = this.checked,
            row = $(this).closest("tr"),
            grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid"),
            dataItem = grid.dataItem(row);

        checkedIds[dataItem.id] = checked;
        if (checked) {
            //-select the row
            row.addClass("k-state-selected");
        } else {
            //-remove selection
            row.removeClass("k-state-selected");
        }
    }

    //on dataBound event restore previous selected rows:
    function onDataBound(e) {
        var view = this.dataSource.view();
        for(var i = 0; i < view.length;i++){
            if(checkedIds[view[i].id]){
                this.tbody.find("tr[data-uid='" + view[i].uid + "']")
                    .addClass("k-state-selected")
                    .find(".checkbox")
                    .attr("checked","checked");
            }
        }           
    }
</script>
```

Comment: So whats the question?

Comment: My question is, how can I pass a selected item ID from one grid to another in a different view?

Comment: Where is the second grid located? is it in the same view? or a different one?

Comment: The grid is located in a different view. The grid in the other view is almost identical, except for some additional columns.